# Finer control over Spring Security on Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have multiple closely related problems in *Spring Security*. I am developing using Spring Boot and am using *Spring Data REST* for creating REST endpoints directly from my repositories.

I have multiple entities and the requirement is to have all these entities as REST endpoints. I am letting `spring-data-rest` handle the creation of these endpoints and I am securing these endpoints by adding `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` to the entity repository methods as and where required. This works great when I am calling an endpoint like `/entity/id`.

But I am facing issues from here. Let's say I have 2 entities, `Entity1` and `Entity2` and they have a `One to One` relationship. Spring data rest allows me to fetch the related `Entity2` data from `Entity1` like `/entity1/id/entity2`. But I have different access rights over `Entity1` and `Entity2` and calling the above endpoint only checks the access rights as set up in the repository for `Entity1` only. So, if a user has access to `Entity1` table and no access to `Entity2` table, he can still see some `Entity2` data via the foreign key relationship of `Entity1`. Is this a correct design?

Moreover we have some custom API endpoints wherein we have to aggregate data from multiple entity repositories. Also, these endpoints themselves have to secured. So, I am using a `@PreAuthorize` over an endpoint method. This works as expected and the endpoint method is called only when the expression is valid. But, when a repository method is called (via a service class of course), the `@PreAuthorize` over that repository method is also evaluated. I would like to have the check done with at the beginning. Is it possible to do so?

Any suggestions to improving the design is also welcome.

Comment: Can't you enforce the security rules at the http level?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution without massively modifying/overriding lots of default Spring DataRest features. I'm working such a package for years now and it's working quite well for me.
Although switching to this package might be a bit overkill for you, it could worth the trouble in the long run because it also a fixes a lot of problem you will meet only months later.

- you can set up permisison rules via annotation directly in the domain objects.
- it checks the permisisons in the DB side, so the traffic between the API and DB is heavily decreased (Only those objects are fetched form the DB which the current user has permission to)
- you can set READ/UPDATE/DELETE/CREATE permissions separately for roles and/or certain users
- you can use pagination on permission filtered collection
- you can use pagination on property-collections too

(+ some extra features like flexible search on multiple properties)

[here is the package](https://github.com/BerryCloud/spring-data-jpa-acl/tree/master/acl) (It's an extension of Spring Data JPA / Data Rest)